# Where can I read Sridhara Swami's commentary on the Bhagavad Gita online in English?

Tags: bhagavad-gita, resource

I would like to read the Sridhara Swami's commentary on the Bhagavad Gita online, in English. Can anyone provide me the relevant link or PDF for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Shridhara Swami's commentary on Bhagavad Gita is available [here](http://www.bhagavad-gita.org/Gita/chapter-01.html). You can select the verse and read relevant commentary for that. Its also available in physical form [here](http://www.exoticindiaart.com/book/details/srimad-bhagavad-gita-with-commentary-by-sridhara-swami-IDK748/).